# Using a button to maps

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button

I'm still new to Android programming.
I want to have a button that when I click it, it will bring me to google maps.

This is my MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, GpsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}

}
```

This is my GPSActivity which is the screen where the google maps is supposed to display

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GpsActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
}

}
```

The XML file for it

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:apiKey="My key" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly the manifest file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gpstest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My key" />

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GpsActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem? Better to use `GoogleMap` instead of `MapView`.

Comment: The problem is that the app crashes everytime i start it.